# Make command not working

Tags: make, github

I want to compile a game from github. I followed this guide http://powdertoy.co.uk/Wiki/W/Compiling_for_Linux.html and when I get to the end when I need to use the make command to compile i get the following error

```
pavle@Pavle:~/TPT$ make powder-sse
gcc -c -w -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DLUACONSOLE -DGRAVFFT -Iincludes/ -D_GNU_SOURCE -m32 -DLIN32 -O3 -ffast-math -ftree-vectorize -funsafe-math-optimizations -march=native -DX86 -DX86_SSE -o build/obj/air.powder-sse.o src/air.c
In file included from /usr/include/math.h:28:0,
                 from src/air.c:18:
/usr/include/features.h:324:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [build/obj/air.powder-sse.o] Error 1
pavle@Pavle:~/TPT$
```

What am I doing wrong I tried using sse2, sse3, 64bit nad opengl(looked it up in the make file) nothing worked. Help please

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev libbz2-dev liblua5.1-0-dev build-essential libfftw3-dev` and `make` it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you on a 64 Bit system? Try to install `gcc-multilib`

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
```

and `make` again.

Comment: sudo apt-get install build-essential

Answer (score 0):

There are one or two things to note: on 64 bit systems, you may need slightly different libraries as another answer mentions, so I should make sure you have all the dependencies (as noted in the comments).

In particular, you seem to be missing the critical `libfftw3-dev`, which provides the 'air' files and headers, and so you get this error:

```
make: *** [build/obj/air.powder-sse.o] Error 1
```

Also, you must use a version of SSE that your CPU can utilise- I just successfully compiled it by using `make powder-sse2` and then running it with `./powder-sse2`. However, by default just typing `make` will create an SSE3 version that will not work on CPUs without that extension.

So I should check your dependencies and then run `make clean` and try the compile again, with a suitable SSE value for your CPU.

[image]